# How to do data binding in polymer with meteor

Tags: data-binding, meteor, polymer, meteor-blaze

I'm very new to data binding and the two frameworks. Right now I'm pretty stuck at how to bind the data within a polymer element.

For example, I have a book list with books' name. If I only use blaze to do the rendering, I would do it in the follow way:

```
//app.js
Template.bookList.helpers({
  books: function () {
    return Books.find({});
  }
});

//app.html
<template name="bookList">
   <h1>List</h1>
   <ul>
   {{#each books}}
    {{> book}}
   {{/each}}
   </ul>
</template>

<template name="book">
  <li>{{name}}</li>
</template>
```

Now I'm using it with polymer, I do:

```
//my-book-list.html
<polymer-element name="my-book-list">
  <template>
     <h1>List</h1>
     <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

//app.html
<template name="bookList">
   <my-book-list>
      <ul>
      {{#each books}}
        {{> book}}
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
   </my-book-list>
</template>

<template name="book">
  <li>{{name}}</li>
</template>
```

So I place the dynamic data inside of the polymer item through the content block. Although it still does the job, I don't want it that way. I want to do the data-binding inside the polymer element, something like(I hope it makes sense to you):

```
//my-book-list.html
<polymer-element name="my-book-list">
  <template bind="{{books}}">
     <h1>List</h1>
     <ul>
       <template repeat>
         <li>{{name}}</li>
       </template>
     </ul>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

//app.html
<template name="bookList">
   <my-book-list></my-book-list>
</template>
```

Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

**Progress**:

I now can put books purely inside the polymer element, the problem now is that it doesn't seem to react when the data change because polymer doesn't observe change of a object, and I am struggling in finding a way to observe all the nested values inside a object:

```
<polymer-element name="my-book-list">
  <template bind="{{books | mapBooks}}">
     <h1>List</h1>
     <ul>
       <template repeat>
         <li>{{name}}</li>
       </template>
     </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer("my-book-list", {
      books: Books.find(),
      mapBooks : function(booksCursor) {
        return booksCursor.map(function(p) { return {id: p.id, name: p.name}})
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: There's an extensive [discussion on Meteor and Polymer](https://github.com/MeteorCommunity/discussions/issues/5) in the MeteorCommunity repo.

Comment: Thanks, the discussion gave me some inspiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a hacky solution, but I don't know if this is the best practice or not:

```
<polymer-element name="my-book-list">
  //Force polymer to update DOM when books.lastUpdate change
  <template bind="{{books.lastUpdate | getBooks}}"> 
     <h1>List</h1>
     <ul>
       <template repeat>
         <li>{{name}}</li>
       </template>
     </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer("my-book-list", {
      ready: function() {
        var books = this.books;
        this.books.observeChanges(  //Observe the change of cursor and update a field
        {
          added: function(id, fields) {
            console.log("Item added");
            books.lastUpdate = new Date();
          },
          changed: function(id, fields) {
            console.log("Item changed");
            books.lastUpdate = new Date();
          },
          removed: function(id, fields) {
            console.log("Item deleted");
            books.lastUpdate = new Date();
          }
        }
      ),
      books: Books.find(),
      getBooks : function() {
        return Books.find().map(function(p) { return {id: p.id, name: p.name}})
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```